# ./gradlew assembleRelease building React Native Web View instead of my project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I'm trying to generate release APK output from my Android project. I've also [automated signing](https://dev.to/zilurrane/generate-release-mode-apk-for-react-native-project-to-publish-on-playstore-5f78) so that I can deploy through terminal.

When I go to `Build > Generate Signed Bundle / APK` in Android Studio, it takes a few minutes, and generates a signed APK at `release/app-release.apk` successfully.

However when I go to my React Native project root and type:

`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`

It takes just about a minute to build, says build succeeded, but only builds React Native Web View, doesn't try to build my project, and generates no APK:

```
can-mbp:myapp-Mobile can$ cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease

> Configure project :react-native-webview
:react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/Can/Documents/Programming/React/myapp-Mobile/node_modules/react-native/android

> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
warning: the transform cache was reset.
Loading dependency graph, done.
info Writing bundle output to:, /Users/Can/Documents/Programming/React/myapp-Mobile/android/app/build/generated/assets/react/release/index.android.bundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 68 asset files
info Done copying assets

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 1s
338 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 336 up-to-date
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**: Here is the output of my `./gradlew projects`

```
Root project 'MyApp'
+--- Project ':@react-native-community_async-storage'
+--- Project ':@react-native-community_geolocation'
+--- Project ':app'
+--- Project ':bugsnag-react-native'
+--- Project ':react-native-geolocation-service'
+--- Project ':react-native-gesture-handler'
+--- Project ':react-native-intercom'
+--- Project ':react-native-linear-gradient'
+--- Project ':react-native-onesignal'
+--- Project ':react-native-static-safe-area-insets'
+--- Project ':react-native-svg'
\--- Project ':react-native-webview'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also try doing clean build

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleDebug or ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

If problem continues, then Run command to know list of projects.

```
./gradlew projects
```

Comment: Yup, for some reason it worked today when I tried it again without clean, but it was probably some cache related thing.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, but after further testing I can confirm that it doesn't work (yesterday I thought it was working when it wasn't)

Comment: share the output of './gradlew projects'

Comment: If possible can you share 'dependencies' block of app/build.gradle and also content of file 'settings.gradle'